# Razor not parsing "~" when it's coming from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using entity framework to display images in a view, the images actually exist in the root folder and only their urls are stored in the database so the action method is written like this :

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
{
    return View(context.Imgs.ToList());
}
```

and in the view

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<img src="@item.Url" />
}
```

provided that I add tilde before urls in the database like so:
~/Content/Images/img.jpg

but then the images don't show up in the view and when I examine them through firebug the src still has the tilde and it's not parsed!

Comment: The `~` transformation to `Url.Content()` only occurs at compile time (Razor to C#). By the time the actual value is read from `@item.Url`, Razor can no longer attempt to transform it. Try `src="@Url.Content(item.Url)"` instead

Comment: @haim770 yes that works, thank you very much.